# How to randomly select a class to instantiate without using switch?

Tags: c++, class, types

I'm refactoring a single 3000+-line class with a tangled web of conditionals and switches into a set of worker classes. Previously part of the constructor would select which "type" of thing to use via code like the following:

```
enum Type { FOO, BAR, BAZ };

Type choices[] = { FOO, FOO, BAR, BAZ }; // weighted towards FOO
m_type = choices[rand()%4];

[...later...]

void Run() {
    switch (m_type) {
        case FOO: do_foo(); break;
        case BAR: do_bar(); break;
        case BAZ: do_baz(); break;
    }
}
```

After refactoring I have separate `TypeFoo`, `TypeBar` and `TypeBaz` classes that each have their own `Run()` methods to do their job. Sadly, its complicated the class selection code. I don't know of any way to keep a list of possible classes to construct, so I have this:

```
Type *m_type;

switch (mrand()%4) {
    case 0: case 1: m_type = new TypeFoo(); break;
    case 1:         m_type = new TypeBar(); break;
    case 2:         m_type = new TypeBaz(); break;
}
```

This is still worth the change because this initialisation code is not called regularly, but its now harder to modify this list, change weightings, etc.

Is there a relatively straightforward to achieve the clarity of the original code?

Comment: +1: Interesting question... :-) Do all those classes inherit from a single base class?

Comment: This would be a little better:
`switch (mrand() %4) {
   case BAR: t = new TypeBar(); break;
   case BAZ: t = new TypeBaz(); break;
    default: t = new TypeFoo(); break; // weighted towards Foo
}`

Comment: Why it's tagged as `template`, when selection has to happen at runtime ?

Comment: @Jon Cage: They do, since a `Type*` pointer can be used to reference all three types in the example.

Comment: I suppose you could also use an array of function pointers, with the function returning a  TypeFoo in there twice.

Comment: @Yourpalal: Assuming that the enum still exists (it doesn't) then yes, that works for that particular case. This is a rather contrived example - the real thing is much hairier.

Comment: @iammilind My mistake. I originally had some ramblings about a possible solution using variadic templates, but decided it was pushing the discussion towards a solution that might not actually be right. Tag removed, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is : a base class and an array of function pointers can help you do that.

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} }; //make ~Base() virtual
struct Foo : Base {};
struct Bar : Base {};
struct Baz : Base {};

template<typename T>
Base *Create() { return new T(); }

typedef Base* (*CreateFn)();

CreateFn create[] = 
         {
              &Create<Foo>, 
              &Create<Foo>,   // weighted towards FOO
              &Create<Bar>, 
              &Create<Baz>
         }; 
const size_t fncount = sizeof(create)/sizeof(*create);

Base *Create()
{
   return create[rand() % fncount](); //forward the call
}
```

Then use it as ([ideone demo](http://www.ideone.com/2f4v4)):

```
int main() {
        Base *obj = Create();
        //work with obj using the common interface in Base

        delete obj; //ok, 
                    //the virtual ~Base() lets you do it 
                    //in a well-defined way
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you wanna add virtual destructor in Base as you're holding a derived class object via a base class pointer.

Comment: +1: That was the kind of thing I had in mind. You beat me to it with a code example though :-)

Comment: Since there are supposedly many more subclasses of `Base`, you could save some boilerplate code by replacing all the `Create*` functions with a template.

Comment: I believe the type of `fncount` should be `size_t`.

Comment: Perfect! I'm kind of annoyed at myself for missing this - I've done before in different contexts. And yes, the template version is delightful: `template <typename T> Base *Create<T>() { return new T(); }`. Thanks @Nawaz!

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Thanks. Template idea is good. Just edited my code example.

Comment: @RobertNorris: Edited the code. Now it has function template, which you probably know how to work with.

Comment: @RobertNorris: don't forget to use a smart pointer to handle the just allocated memory :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a common base class (if you've not already got one) and then using [a factory class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to encapsulate the creation process. The factory would just return a pointer to your base class which has the prototype run method.

Something along these lines:

```
class Type
{
    virtual void Run() = 0;
};

class TypeFoo : public Type
{
public:
    TypeFoo() {};
    virtual void Run() {};
    static Type* Create() { return new TypeFoo(); };
};

class TypeBar : public Type
{
public:
    TypeBar() {};
    virtual void Run() {};
    static Type* Create() { return new TypeBar(); };
};

class TypeBaz : public Type
{
public:
    TypeBaz() {};
    virtual void Run() {};
    static Type* Create() { return new TypeBaz(); };
};

class TypeFactory
{
    typedef Type* (*CreateFn)();

public:
    static Type* RandomTypeFooWeighted()
    {
        CreateFn create[] = 
        {
            TypeFoo::Create, 
            TypeFoo::Create,   // weighted towards FOO
            TypeBar::Create, 
            TypeBaz::Create
        };   
        const int fncount = sizeof(create)/sizeof(*create);
        return create[ rand()%fncount ]();
    }
};
```

So to use it you can just call:

```
Type *t = TypeFactory::RandomTypeFooWeighted();
```

Credit to Nawaz for the function pointer bits and bobs.