# Picking random subclass in C++

Tags: c++, random, subclass, abstract

I am writing a game. Its structure looks like this - 
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seF16.png) .

Now, I have a map in another class called World(Basically an array of organisms), where I want to spawn n random organisms.

I know that I could do rand() % subclassesCount and do if/switch statements, but what if I had 1000 types of animals and plants? Would I have to specify them all in my code? Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7803345

Comment: Contrary to a beginner's intuition, good OOP designs use subclassing rather sparingly. You don't want to have 1000 subclasses for animals and plants. Your goal should be to turn those 1000 subclasses into 1000 different objects of significantly fewer classes. I think the classical Design Patterns book is still a good read to grasp those basics.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two cases:

Case 1: No constraint on organism spawned.

Solution:

You can simply assign each organism a unique identity number(make a array) and use index number to choose organism randomly.

Case 2: Each organism should be unique.

Solution:
Maintain another bool array which will store whether this organism has been spawned or not.`bool status[1000];//remember to initialize it with 0.`